# Como capturar um dados de um SELECT em javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

sou novo na área e estou estudando. Existe um projeto para captação de empréstimos, onde solicita o valor e com base na quantidade de prestações, existe um percentual de juros. Acontece que escolhi a forma de SELECT para captar as prestações. Mas não estou conseguindo captar isso. Vejam abaixo o trecho do html e js.

```js
function calcular(){
    var txtvalor = document.getElementById('txtvalor')
    var opcao = document.getElementById('opcao')
    var opcoes = opcao.options[opcao.selectedIndex].value
    var valparcelas = document.getElementById('valparcelas')
    var valtotal = document.getElementById('valtotal')

    switch(opcoes.value){
        case 6:
            alert('voce escolheu 6')
        break
    }
}
```

```html
<legend>Selecione o modelo de prestações:</legend>
                <select id="opcao">
                    <option value="3">3x</option>
                    <option value="6">6x</option>
                    <option value="12">12x</option>
                    <option value="18">18x</option>
                    <option value="24">24x</option>
                    <option value="36">36x</option>
                </select>

                <input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="calcular()" class="botao">
```

Esse resultado de exibição é apenas para teste, os cálculo e a forma como exibir eu tenho posteriormente.

Comment: Da maneira que fez está quase correta, aconteceu 2 erros. Primeiro erro: já pegou o value na variável opcoes, ou seja, no switch não precisa de **opcoes.value** só precisa de opcoes. Segundo erro: no case está comparando com um número **6** quando o que vem do select é uma string, ou seja, basta colocar aspas nos cases exemplo `'6'` .

Comment: Opa, realmente, achei que precisaria atribuir o value novamente, agora funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado pela força.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vê se te ajuda, brother.

```js
function calcular() {

  var opcao = document.getElementById('opcao').value;

  switch (opcao) {
    case '6':
      alert('voce escolheu 6');
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<legend>Selecione o modelo de prestações:</legend>
<select id="opcao">
  <option value="3">3x</option>
  <option value="6">6x</option>
  <option value="12">12x</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="calcular()" class="botao">
```